# What trait makes uninitialized_copy(_n) sustituable by copy(_n)?

Tags: c++, initialization, copy, type-traits

I am trying to understand the meaning of the types properties and supported operations, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types .

I have a library that implements in terms of low level functions things similar to `std::copy_n`, of course I would have to implement `uninitialized_copy` as well, but for many of the types, that are in some sense trivial, I don't want to repeat code and delegate one to the other.

**What property makes `uninitialized_copy(_n)` semantically substitutable by `copy(_n)`?**

My guess is that it is *`std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>::value`*, but I am not sure.
The justification is that if something is trivially default constructible I can skip the initialization before the assignment.

(Initially I though it could be `std::is_trivially_assignable<TSource, T>::value`)

Of course I could play safe and ask for `std::is_trivial<T>::value`, but I want to be more targeted.
I know there are could be Machiavellian or misleading definitions of these traits, but suppose I want to trust them.

---

Example code:

```
template<class... As, class... Bs>
auto uninitialized_copy_n(
    my_iterator<As...>   first, Size count,
    my_iterator<Bs...> d_first
)-> my_iterator<Bs...> {
    using T1 = typename my_iterator<As...>::value_type;
    using T2 = typename my_iterator<Bs...>::value_type;
    if constexpr(std::is_trivially_constructible<T2>::value){
        return copy_n(first, count, d_first);
    }
    ... another implementation or abort 
}
```

Comment: You can refer to the implementation of [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ranges_uninitialized.h#L318), which is `is_trivial_v<_OutType> && is_nothrow_assignable_v<_OutType&, iter_reference_t<_Iter>>`.

Comment: @康桓瑋  Thank you for the pointer! I am going to use that condition then. It looks at first glance that this is asking too much. For example`is_trivial` means trivial destructor, why would I care about that during copy. On the other hand I am probably missing something very subtle.

Comment: @alfC to be trivally copyable requires the destructor to be trival as well https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable

Comment: @DaveS, ok, there is an extra subtlety here that is that it involves two types one for source and one for destination (although 99% of the time is going to be the same two). So I guess that you mean that `Trivial_Assignable_from_TSource` implies trivial destruction (too bad there is not such named concept).

Comment: @DaveS, I accept the point about destruction. I wonder now if `is_trivially_assignable_v<T&, InReference>` and `is_trivial_v<T> && is_nothrow_assignable_v<T&, InReference>` are equivalent. Probably not, because I need `std::is_trivially_(default)_constructible` also which I realized early on is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `uninitialized_copy` with `copy`, the two actions must be equivalent:

- `uninitialized_copy`: construct a new object of type `Destination` from an object of type `Source`
- `copy`: assume an object of type `Destination` exists and assign to it from an object of type `Source`

One must put sufficient requirements on the type such that the destination object exists and that construction and assignment give the same value.

`is_trivially_default_constructible` is neither necessary nor sufficient to assume an object exists at a memory location. Instead, the destination type must be an [implicit lifetime type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime). That is not a recursive condition, so we must require the type be an implicit lifetime type, and recursively all members or subobjects are implicit lifetime types.

For example, scalars or classes with trivial default constructor and trivial destructor will work.

Secondly, we need construction and assignment to give the same result. This is impossible if these operations aren't trivial. But in C++, the value of an object is only guaranteed to be unchanged by such operations for trivially copyable types, which tie the value to the representation. Therefore, we probably want the destination to be trivially copyable.

This gives us:

- `std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<Destination>`
- `std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Destination>`
- `std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Destination, const Source&>`
- `std::is_trivially_assignable_v<Destination&, const Source&>`
- `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Destination>`

This simplifies to:

- `std::is_trivial_v<Destination>`
- `std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Destination, const Source&>`
- `std::is_trivially_assignable_v<Destination&, const Source&>`

Note that [libstdc++ requires both types to be trivial and the Destination assignable and constructible from the Source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h#L177). The comment references a slightly different condition on the ranges algorithm instead.

The libstdc++ requirement has observable differences. See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/8YT8brz1r). `value` should be `1` (from construction) but is being populated with `2` (from assignment). I cannot find any license given to implementations to differ in this way.

The libstdc++ logic was recently [found to be buggy](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102064) and likely still is.

Comment: Interesting, it seems then that when uninitialized_copy(_n) is sustitutable by copy(_n) the converse is also true. I wasn't expecting it.

Comment: Doesn't `is_trivial_v` imply `is_trivially_constructible_v` (and `is_trivially_assignable_v`)?

Comment: `is_trivial` places no restrictions on cross-type construction or assignment.

Comment: Seems to be true for cross assignment, but not for cross construction. https://godbolt.org/z/Y5ooMxW9n . Is it a bug, or I am missing something?

Comment: That's only because defining that constructor suppresses the default constructor. Add `A() = default;`

Comment: You are correct of course! Final follow up question (for now), when we are talking about cross types: why would matter if the type `is_trivally_copyable` (assignable to itself), which `is_trivial` seems to imply.